# React Material UI Textfield onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/formdata")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setFormData(data));
  }, []);

  console.log("Form Data", formData);

  //Sorting by order
  let attr;
  form.forms.map((y) => {
    return (attr = y.formAttributes.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.order < b.order ? -1 : 1;
    }));
  });

return (
{attr.map((attri, index) => {
              return (
                <TextField
                  key={index}
                  label={attri.label}
                  value={formData[attri.datakey] || ""}
                  onChange={event => {const {value} = event.target; setFormData({formData: value})}}
                />
              );
            })}
)
```

I would like to ask help on how to manage multiple fields in Textfield onChange area? Currently, if I am going to input a value there are no changes that is happening.

Here's my code.

Tried the approach of using e.target.value however it would still stay the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is `attr` reactive? i.e. is it part of your component's state? Please show the actual code, not pictures of it

Comment: codesandbox link ?

Comment: Please don't put the entire code as a comment. Put it into your question and surround it with triple backticks i.e. ```

Comment: send your `formData` state

Comment: @Moeinmoeinnia the state is {type: "abcd", severity: "major", status: "ok", description: "improve"}

Comment: @smac89 already edited my question and put my source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a **name** attribute, where the 'name' is the **key** of the key-value-pair in your object.

e.g.

```
  <TextField
              key={index}
              name="somename"
              label={attri.label}
              value={formData[attri.datakey] || ""}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
```

Then you can update the field like that.

```
setFormData({
   ...formData,
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value // becomes "somename: some value"
})
```